# Display a different number than what is in the table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have a C# program that displays a list of patients with medications where there is a conflict in the medications to be noted by the nurse. We have severity levels, 1,2,3 and 9 in the table. But if there is a '9' we want to display a "U" for unknown. Can I do this here?

```
       //var warnings = new List<POWarningsDetail>();
        while (r != null && r.Read())
        {
            war.ConflictDesc = r.To("CONFLICT_DESC", "");
            war.SeverityLevel = r.To("SEVERITY_LEVEL", "");
        }
    });

}
warnings = warnings.Where(w => w.ConflictDesc != null && w.ConflictDesc != string.Empty).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably accomplish that in your UI layer - web page or WPF view. You can use something like:

```
label.Text = warning.SeverityLevel == 9 ? "U" : warning.SeverityLevel.ToString();
```

Comment: You posted this just as I started writing almost the exact same thing.

Comment: would you put this here?public String SeverityLevel { get; set; }

Comment: Nope, since that is your data object property. Instead, use that code in your front end.